# Case insensitive and diacritial marks insensitive filtering with Telerik RadGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, telerik-grid

The title says pretty much everything. What can be done to have a case insensitive and diacritical marks insensitive filtering with Telerik RadGridView?

I've found many posible solutions with Google, but none of them was simple to use, plus, in many cases it changed the UI behaviour of the RadGridView making it less attractive to final users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over the years my experience and skills have growth, so finally I came up with a simple-to-use solution. It works with Telerik UI for WinForms 2017 R1 or newer, and Visual Studio 2015 or newer.

Here is the helper class, `RadGridViewHelper`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using Telerik.WinControls.Data;
using Telerik.WinControls.UI;

namespace MySoftware.Helpers
{
    internal static class RadGridViewHelper
    {
        private class CustomStringFilteringClass
        {
            private RadGridView RadGridView { get; }
            private bool _enabled;
            private ReadOnlyCollection<string> StringColumns { get; }

            public CustomStringFilteringClass(RadGridView radGridView)
            {
                RadGridView = radGridView;
                StringColumns = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(GetStringColumns(radGridView));
            }

            public void Enable()
            {
                if (_enabled) throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't call this method twice");
                _enabled = true;

                RadGridView.EnableCustomFiltering = true;
                RadGridView.CustomFiltering += RadGridViewOnCustomFiltering;
            }

            private void RadGridViewOnCustomFiltering(object sender, GridViewCustomFilteringEventArgs e)
            {
                if (RadGridView.FilterDescriptors.Count == 0) return;

                var row = e.Row;

                foreach (var stringColumn in StringColumns)
                {
                    var filterDescriptors = RadGridView.FilterDescriptors.Where(
                        x => x.PropertyName == stringColumn).ToList();
                    if (filterDescriptors.Count != 1)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    var filterDescriptor = filterDescriptors.First();
                    var cellValue = ((string) row.Cells[stringColumn].Value).ToLowerInvariant();
                    if (filterDescriptor.GetType() == typeof(CompositeFilterDescriptor))
                    {
                        if (!CompositeFilterEvaluateString((CompositeFilterDescriptor) filterDescriptor, cellValue,
                            RadGridView.MasterTemplate.DataView.FilterEvaluate, row))
                        {
                            e.Visible = false;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (!FilterEvaluateString(filterDescriptor, cellValue,
                        RadGridView.MasterTemplate.DataView.FilterEvaluate, row))
                    {
                        e.Visible = false;
                        return;
                    }
                }

                var nonStringFilterDescriptors = RadGridView.FilterDescriptors.Where(
                    x => !StringColumns.Contains(x.PropertyName));
                foreach (var filterDescriptor in nonStringFilterDescriptors)
                {
                    if (!RadGridView.MasterTemplate.DataView.FilterEvaluate(filterDescriptor, row))
                    {
                        e.Visible = false;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

            private static bool CompositeFilterEvaluateString(CompositeFilterDescriptor compositeFilterDescriptor,
                string cellValue, Func<FilterDescriptor, GridViewRowInfo, bool> gridFilterEvaluate, GridViewRowInfo row)
            {
                switch (compositeFilterDescriptor.LogicalOperator)
                {
                    case FilterLogicalOperator.And:
                        if (compositeFilterDescriptor.FilterDescriptors.Any(filterDescriptor =>
                        {
                            if (filterDescriptor.GetType() == typeof(CompositeFilterDescriptor))
                                return !CompositeFilterEvaluateString((CompositeFilterDescriptor) filterDescriptor,
                                    cellValue, gridFilterEvaluate, row);
                            return !FilterEvaluateString(filterDescriptor, cellValue, gridFilterEvaluate, row);
                        }))
                            return false;
                        break;
                    case FilterLogicalOperator.Or:
                        if (compositeFilterDescriptor.FilterDescriptors.All(filterDescriptor =>
                        {
                            if (filterDescriptor.GetType() == typeof(CompositeFilterDescriptor))
                                return !CompositeFilterEvaluateString((CompositeFilterDescriptor) filterDescriptor,
                                    cellValue, gridFilterEvaluate, row);
                            return !FilterEvaluateString(filterDescriptor, cellValue, gridFilterEvaluate, row);
                        }))
                            return false;
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }

            private static bool FilterEvaluateString(FilterDescriptor filterDescriptor, string cellValue,
                Func<FilterDescriptor, GridViewRowInfo, bool> gridFilterEvaluate, GridViewRowInfo row)
            {
                var filterDescriptorValue = ((string) filterDescriptor.Value).ToLowerInvariant();
                switch (filterDescriptor.Operator)
                {
                    case FilterOperator.Contains:
                        if (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(cellValue, filterDescriptorValue,
                                CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace) == -1)
                            return false;
                        break;
                    case FilterOperator.NotContains:
                        if (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(cellValue, filterDescriptorValue,
                                CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace) != -1)
                            return false;
                        break;
                    case FilterOperator.StartsWith:
                        if (!CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IsPrefix(cellValue, filterDescriptorValue,
                            CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace))
                            return false;
                        break;
                    case FilterOperator.EndsWith:
                        if (!CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IsSuffix(cellValue, filterDescriptorValue,
                            CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace))
                            return false;
                        break;
                    case FilterOperator.IsEqualTo:
                        if (String.Compare(cellValue, filterDescriptorValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace) != 0)
                            return false;
                        break;
                    case FilterOperator.IsNotEqualTo:
                        if (String.Compare(cellValue, filterDescriptorValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace) == 0)
                            return false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        if (!gridFilterEvaluate.Invoke(filterDescriptor, row))
                            return false;
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }

        private static List<string> GetStringColumns(RadGridView radGridView)
        {
            var retVal = new List<string>();
            foreach (var column in radGridView.Columns)
            {
                if (column.DataType == typeof(string))
                {
                    retVal.Add(column.Name);
                }
            }
            return retVal;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Enables custom string filtering on <paramref name="radGridView"/>. It is case insensitive and
        /// tolerates differences in diacritical marks. For example, in a "equals" comparision, the value
        /// 'ëMúa' is treated as its equal to 'EmÜâ'.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="radGridView">Instance of <see cref="RadGridView"/> in which custom string filtering
        /// will be enabled.</param>
        public static void CustomStringFiltering(RadGridView radGridView)
        {
            var customFiltering = new CustomStringFilteringClass(radGridView);
            customFiltering.Enable();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage is simple:

`RadGridViewHelper.CustomStringFiltering(radGridView);`

Where `radGridView` is the instance of the class `RadGridView` to which the string filtering behaviour will be changed.

I'm putting this here in a Q&A-style, as **encouraged** in here: [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions - Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Hope it helps and saves time and headaches to someone.